# Trouble with read.coda function in R

Tags: r, bayesian, mcmc

I'm having trouble reading an Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output using the `read.coda` function from the `coda` library for Bayesian diagnostics in R. My issue is that the mcmc representation of the data is being padded with `NA`. Here is what the function is returning:

```
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Thinning interval = 1 
    Rho Sigma2
  1 0.204     NA
  2 0.205     NA
  3 0.206     NA
  4    NA  0.147
  5    NA  0.148
  6    NA  0.149
```

My expected output is

```
Markov Chain Monte Carlo (MCMC) output:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Thinning interval = 1 
    Rho Sigma2
  1 0.204     0.147
  2 0.205     0.148
  3 0.206     0.149
```

The formatting requires an index files (.txt) telling you each variable's name and the range of rows, and the chain file (.txt) contains the variables value and iteration number. Here is a basic working example that replicates the issue I'm having. My `index.file` looks like:

```
Rho     1   3
Sigma2  4   6
```

where rows 1-3 correspond to values for Rho, 4-6 for Sigma2 and my `out.file` looks like:

```
1   0.204
2   0.205
3   0.206
4   0.147
5   0.148
6   0.149
```

Does anyone know why I'm not returning the expected output?

Comment: Maybe `debug(read.coda)` and stepping through loading your file might be informative.